# Why is this query with a nested select faster when I include the where clause twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a large sql query that had a nested select in the from clause.

Similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
     ( SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE some_num = 20) 
    WHERE some_num = 20
```

In my sql query if I remove the outer "some_num" = 20 it takes 5 times as long . Shouldent these querys run in almost exactly the same time, if not wouldn't having the the additional where slow it down slightly?

What am I not understanding about how sql querys work?

Here is the original query in question

```
SELECT a.ITEMNO                                                       AS Item_No,
       a.DESCRIPTION                                                  AS Item_Description,
       UNITPRICE / 100                                                AS Retail_Price,
       b.UNITSALES                                                    AS Units_Sold,
       ( Dollar_Sales )                                               AS Dollar_Sales,
       ( Dollar_Cost )                                                AS Dollar_Cost,
       ( Dollar_Sales ) - ( Dollar_Cost )                             AS Gross_Profit,
       ( Percent_Page * c.PAGECOST )                                  AS Page_Cost,
       ( Dollar_Sales - Dollar_Cost - ( Percent_Page * c.PAGECOST ) ) AS Net_Profit,
       Percent_Page * 100                                             AS Percent_Page,
       ( CASE
           WHEN UNITPRICE = 0 THEN NULL
           WHEN Percent_Page = 0 THEN NULL
           WHEN ( Dollar_Sales - Dollar_Cost - ( Percent_Page * c.PAGECOST ) ) > 0 THEN 0
           ELSE ( ceiling(abs(Dollar_Sales - Dollar_Cost - ( Percent_Page * c.PAGECOST )) / ( UNITPRICE / 100 )) )
         END )                                                        AS Break_Even,
       b.PAGENO                                                       AS Page_Num
FROM   (SELECT PAGENO,
               OFFERITEM,
               UNITSALES,
               UNITPRICE,
               ( DOLLARSALES / 100 )                                      AS Dollar_Sales,
               ( DOLLARCOST / 10000 )                                     AS Dollar_Cost,
               (( CAST(STUFF(PERCENTPAGE, 2, 0, '.') AS DECIMAL(9, 6)) )) AS Percent_Page
        FROM   OFFERITEMS
        WHERE  LEFT(OFFERITEM, 6) = 'CH1301'
               AND PERCENTPAGE > 0) AS b
       INNER JOIN ITEMMAST a
         ON a.EDPNO = 1 * RIGHT(OFFERITEM, 8)
       LEFT JOIN OFFERS c
         ON c.OFFERNO = 'CH1301'
WHERE  LEFT(OFFERITEM, 6) = 'CH1301'
ORDER  BY Net_Profit DESC
```

Notice the two

```
WHERE left(OFFERITEM,6) = 'CH1301'
```

If I remove the outer Where then the query takes 5 times as long

As requested the Execution plan excuse the crappy upload

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JvzB.png

Comment: Before replying to your question , I just want to understand that why you are applying the same condition in the outer query when you have already get the result from the inner query.

Comment: Show the actual query and execution plans. In the example you have given it won't make any difference.

Comment: Also, the one reason where 'where' clause can make your query slower is that you don't proper have indexing on the column.

Comment: I agree with Martin - it shouldn't make a difference. Just take a look at both execution plans and see if it really is a difference there.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?--can you include it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the column OFFERITEM in an index but PERCENTPAGE is not?

In your inner query you reference both these columns, in the outer query you only reference OFFERITEM.

Difficult to say without seeing the execution plan, but it could be that the outer query is causing the optimizer to run an 'index scan' whereas the inner query would cause a full table scan.

On a separate note, you should definitely modify:

```
WHERE left(OFFERITEM,6) ='CH1301'
```

to:

```
where offeritem like 'CH1301%'
```

As this will allow an index seek if there is an index on offeritem.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer - for other users, can you indicate which part of my answer helped you? I guess all of it? :)